# Sql Server Replication of Columns deleted columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have 2 databases and I want to do a replication of a certain table with certain columns.

When I was creating the publication, I selected the table and unchecked all the columns that I do not want to replicate. 
**However it deleted all the columns for the subscriber.**

Is there a way I can replicate certain columns of a table with sending default values or nulls to the subscribers?